# Can't store and load an arraylist in an object file

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to store an object of type Aluno:

```
public class Aluno implements Serializable{
   String nome;
   String estado; //licenciatura ou mestrado
   float montanteMax;
public Aluno(String nome, String estado, float montanteMax) {
    this.nome=nome;
    this.estado=estado;
    this.montanteMax=montanteMax;
public String toString() {
    return "Aluno nome=" + nome + ", estado=" + estado + ", montanteMax=" montanteMax; } }
```

arraylist in an object file (as requested by the teacher) so when an user creates a new profile, I write to an object file so I can later, for example, load the information in the file so I can compare to see if the user is already created, for example.
But I can't store an ArrayList because it says "can't read file".
Here's the code of the function that writes in the file:

```
private void escrever_ficheiro(String nome, String estado, float montanteMax) {
    File f = new File("utilizadores_objetos.txt");
    // teste
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome,estado,montanteMax);
        listaAlunos.add(aluno);
        oos.writeObject(listaAlunos);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao criar ficheiro");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao escrever para o ficheiro");
    }

}
```

and the one that loads it:

```
public static void ler_ficheiro() {
File f = new File("utilizadores_objetos.txt");
if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linha;
        if ((linha=br.readLine()) != null) {
            br.close();
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                 listaAlunos = (ArrayList<Aluno>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Não encontrei o ficheiro");
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Erro a abrir ficheiro.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Erro a ler ficheiro.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Erro a converter objeto.");
    } 
  }
}
```

I also have this function so I can create the arrayList:

```
public class AplicacaoViagem{
    private List<Aluno> listaAlunos;
public AplicacaoViagem() {
   super();
   listaAlunos = new ArrayList<>();
 }  
}
```

and I get the "listaAlunos cannot be resolve into a variable" error in eclipse. 
Each piece of code is in a different .java file and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It is not clear if you are having an issue with saving or reading the file?

Comment: I can read and write one object without any problem, but when I try to implement reading and writing an array it can write but it cannot read.

Comment: Why reading the file twice? Try to remove FileReader/BufferedReader code

Comment: I previously had just the bottom part and it didn't work anyway, so I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the whole array to a file, write each element to a file. You have the right idea with the `toString()` override.

I would change the `toString()` as follows

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("%s:%s:%f", nome, estado, montanteMax);
}
```

Then you can write out your items to file as such:

```
public void writeToFile(List<Aluno> objectList) {
   String data = objectList
                   .stream()
                   .map(obj -> obj.toString())
                   .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

   Files.write(Paths.get("utilizadores_objetos.txt"),
               data.toByte(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
               StandardOpenOption.CREATE, 
               StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

Then if you want to read the file back in you would do something like:

```
public List<Aluno> readFile() throws IOException {
   List<Aluno> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("utilizadores_objetos.txt"))
                      .stream()
                      .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
                      .map(s -> new Aluno(s))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
   return list;
}
```

Then add in your `Aluno` class this constructor:

```
public Aluno(String data) {
   String items = data.split(":");
   nome = items[0];
   estado = items[1];
   montanteMax = Float.parseFloat(items[2]);
}
```

Make sure you add your proper error handling.

This should get you what you're looking for, reading and writing to file.